# Tridion 2011 CMS: Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html

Tags: css, content-management-system, tridion-2011, mode

I've installed a custom msi on the Tridion 2011 CMS which updates many Tridion configs and do not have an insight of what configuration got changed. Now all css' are interpreted as text/html instead of text/css and CMS isnt loading correctly. The error in Chrome is : 
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://sf1-dv9-iub-cm.wellsfargo.com:12300/WebUI/Editors/CME/Views/Dashboard/Dashboard_v6.1.0.55920.15_.aspx?mode=css".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phew - The issue seemed with the System.config file. Copied it from a properly working environment and the messed up environment is back to normal! Thanks all for checking.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you were getting a server-side error -- probably due to an error in your configuration or failure to load some assemblies.

You can check that by going directly to the URL mentioned. It's likely an error page with details on the issue. Alternatively, you can check the Application log in Event Viewer for any warnings by ASP.NET from the time of the request.